# incorrect node_module getting deployed to lambda as based on OS

Tags: lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm using the serverless framework to create a lambda function and to deploy all works great locally (on my mac) when testing by invoking it, but once its deployed onto AWS I get the following error:

```
    2018-09-03T20:16:26.800Z    3bb86928-afb6-11e8-8ff0-912d71d35609    Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v57-linux-x64-glibc
Found: [node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'
```

Is there a way in Serverless to do a `yarn/npm install` so all the packages installed match the OS they're running on?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to resolve this error by performing the following step locally before deploying:

```
npm rebuild --target_platform=linux --target_libc=glibc
```

This should install the version of the grpc binary that is needed on the system you are deploying to.